# Консольный эмулятор терминала для linux со вкладками

Tags: linux

Сам я пользуюсь в консоли linux таким эмулятором терминала как tmux, но недавно у коллеги подсмотрел такой эмулятор, как Yakuake и очень мне понравилась в нём фича "вкладки" по горизонтали.

Но вот беда - Yakuake работает только под X Windows, в то время как мне хочется в одном из четырёх окон tmux держать несколько сессий со вкладками по горизонтали.

Есть такие эмуляторы терминала, которые работаю в консоли?

Перечитал списки популярных [эмуляторов в википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#Linux) – что-то не вижу ничего похожего. :(

PS Коллега работает за ноутбуком с диагональю 14 дюймов, распахнутая на весь экран консоль выглядит хорошо, вкладки удобно позволяют переключаться между экранами. У меня три монитора по 21 дюйм на столе, распахнутая на весь экран консоль не нужна, а вот tmux'ом удобно поделить экран на 4 части (но не больше - слишком мелко). Одну из четвертушек я готов отдать под табы.

> а какое принципиальное отличие окон tmux'а от вкладок эмулятора
>   терминала?

Прошу прощения за неточность формулировок. Когда я писал "окно tmux" я имел ввиду "панель tmux". На одном из мониторов у меня висит SSH-сессия (на весь экран развёрнутая), в ней запущен tmux, и весь монитор разделён на 4 панели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Табы не видны одновременно, а все 4 панели я вижу одновременно (и это тоже очень удобно), но готов нижнюю панель справа отдать под набор 5-6 табов.

Так понятнее объяснение?

Comment: эмм... а какое принципиальное отличие окон tmux'а от вкладок эмулятора терминала?

Comment: Ctrl + A + W, еяпп, для screen показывает текущие окна. Более того, эту информацию можно сделать строкой статуса. Уверен, что такого же можно достичь и в tmux.

Comment: Ваще ничего не понял. Давайте пофантазирую: вам нужно, чтобы, чтобы один из подключённых мониторов работал без X?

Comment: @AK, просто запусти вложенную сессию tmux'а в панели и не изобретай велосипед ;)... в первом приближении, надо будет ей только поменять prefix-key...

Comment: наличествует смешение понятий: [tmux — это мультиплексор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80), а не [эмулятор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8). и исправить вопрос не представляется возможным ввиду того, что потеряется его смысл (сейчас он ошибочный ввиду упомянутой ошибки с определениями). скорректируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтобы он имел хоть какой-то смысл.